# Can you bind data from one scope to update when another changes in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

My web app depends on one specific variable changing throughout the user's visit.  It controls what data the user will see at any given time, essentially akin to a TAG.

If the `$scope.tagid = 1`, is it possible to have another angular model to instantly update its own dataset when tagid is changed to $scop.tagid = 2?

```
 <script >
function PageCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.text = '<?=$tagid?>';
}
 $scope.showThread = function(tagid) {
 $http({method: 'GET', url: 'api/example/thread/id/' + tagid}).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.appDetail = data;               //set view model
          $scope.view = './Partials/detail.html'; //set to detail view
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.appDetail = data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = status;
          $scope.view = './Partials/detail.html';
      });
 }
</script>
    <div ng-controller="PageCtrl">
        <input ng-model='text' />
      <ul>
        <li >
          <span>{{text}}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Above is the skeleton of what i'm looking to do.

I realize that if I wanted to, I could call showThread() after each user action and update the data...however, because of the awy I'm looking to set up the site, It makes more sense to only change the tagid, then have everything else update immediately after, rather than picking and choosing each part of the site I want to update.  i.e. there may, in addition to showThread(), be updateHeader(), changeSidebar() etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Look up $watch if both variables are in the same controller, else you should use a service.

Comment: Looks like a good place to start. thanks

Comment: You could also use an event to broadcast changes to the specific variable.  In the service's set function, broadcast the change - an alternative to watches (your service would depend on rootScope in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have personally had success using a service; **Assuming that you are using 2 controllers on 1 page, I would create a service like this:

```
MyApp.app.service("tagDataSvc", function () {

var _tagId = {};

return {
    getTagId: function () {
        return _tagId;
    },
    setTagId: function (value) {
        _tagId = value;
    }
};

});
```

Next, inject this service into the controllers where this will be used.

In your main controller where you are controlling the TagId (PageCtrl), you would need to set the shared tagId value with a call to the service: `tagDataSvc.setTagId($scope.text)` You can do this explicitly, or add a $watch on $scope.text, or whatever you prefer.

Finally, in the second controller that you want to automagically update, add a $watch on this service's getTagId() function like so:

```
  $scope.$watch(function () { return tagDataSvc.getTagId(); }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue != null) {
            $scope.tagId2 = newValue;
            //reload whatever needs updating here
        }
    }, true);
```

Comment: very nice code. thanks!  I'm sure im going to have fun getting this working.